# How to cut ifconfig to get eth* details alone?

Tags: linux, bash, grep, ifconfig

I'm writing a script to print ethtool details of ifconfig.

Sample output should be from ifconfig is like,

```
eth0
eth1
eth2
```

I have tried using below command,

```
root@bt# ifconfig | cut -d ":" -f 1
```

But could not able to achieve the same.

Actually, i need to get these `eth*` and pass in

```
root@bt# ethtool <arg1> where arg1=eth*
```

to get results :-) can you please help me to get crop from ifconfig. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `grep` & `ifconfig` :

```
ifconfig | grep -o '^eth[0-9]\+'
```

Or with only `grep` :

```
grep -oP '^ *\Keth[0-9]+' /proc/net/dev
```

Answer (score 1):

No.

```
$ awk -F: '$1 ~ "eth" { print $1 }' /proc/net/dev
  eth0
```