# Parse interfaces from ifconfig

Tags: regex, sed, grep

I'm trying to get the list of networks interfaces from the command-line in this form:

```
"wlan0","eth0","lo"
```

I don't need to get them in a special order.

I can do this:

```
wlan0,eth0,lo
```

with this super non-optimized command, after having searched a lot and after I think I've reached my limits:

```
ifconfig -a | grep -E '' | sed -n 's/^\([^ ]\+\).*/\1/p' | tr -d '\n' | sed s/:/,/g | sed 's/.$//'
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9976928/parsing-data-from-ifconfig-with-awk-or-sed and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12664473/how-to-cut-ifconfig-to-get-eth-details-alone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll add this one to the pile.  Add the quotes in the first sed, then just join the lines with paste.

```
ifconfig -a | sed -n 's/^\([^ ]\+\).*/"\1"/p' | paste -sd ","
```

This is better than tr since there's no trailing comma.

Better yet, since ifconfig -a output can't really be counted on to stay consistent, check /sys/class/net

```
ls /sys/class/net | sed -e 's/^\(.*\)$/"\1"/' | paste -sd ","
```

Comment: Interesting, but you still have `:` character

Comment: hmm, not on my flavor of ifconfig.  asker should have posted the ifconfig -a output in the question, this seems to vary quite a bit from system to system.   really should be grabbing this info from /sys/class/net or /proc/net/dev anyway.

Comment: ls /sys/class/net | sed -e 's/^\(.*\)$/"\1"/' | paste -sd ","
This is perfect with "tr -d '\n'" on the end! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
ifconfig -a | sed -e '/^ /d;/^$/d;s/\([^ ]*\) .*/"\1"/' | tr '\n' ','
```

There are three commands we're executing:

1. `/^ /d` this command checks if the line starts with a space. If it does, "d" deletes it (and goes to the next line without executing the remaining commands).
2. `/^$/d` this command deletes empty lines
3. `s/\([^ ]*\) .*/"\1"/` this command is reached when the above commands fail (ie., now we have a line that isn't empty *and* doesn't start with a space). What it does is capture as much characters that aren't spaces as it can, and then matches all characters from the space to the end of the line. The replacement string contains the special `\1` "variable", which contains the captured string (ie. the interface name). We also include it between quotes.

After the sed command, we have the interfaces between double quotes, but one per line. To fix this we use `tr '\n' ','` to replace newline characters with commas.

Hope this helps =)

Comment: There will be a pesky final comma to get rid of.

Comment: Yeah thanks, it helped me a lot, so I came up with this to get rid of the final coma:
ifconfig -a | sed -e '/^ /d;/^$/d;s/\([^ ]*\) .*/"\1"/' | tr '\n' ','
however with this command there's still this character ':' before each comma

Answer (score 2):

```
ifconfig -a | awk '/^[^[[:space:]]/{a[NR]=$1} END{count=asort(a,b);for(i=1;i<count;i++){printf "\"%s\",", b[i]}; printf "\"%s\"\n", b[count]}'
```

Answer (score 2):

With `Perl` in a shell :

```
ifconfig |
perl -ane '
    END{print "\042", join("\042,\042", @a), "\042\n"}
    $a[$c++] = $1 if /^(\w+)/; 
'
```

Try the following if you use `bash` :

```
x=( $(ifconfig | grep -o '^[[:alnum:]]\+') )

for ((i=0; i<${#x[@]} -1; i++)); do
    printf '"%s",' ${x[i]}
done

printf '"%s"\n' ${x[-1]}
```

Based on Tom McClure one but without parsing ls :

```
printf '"%s"\n' $(
    printf '%s\n' /sys/class/net/* | cut -d '/' -f 5
) | paste -sd ","
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be better to parse the corresponding nodes in the `/sys` filesystem if you have that, but try

```
ifconfig -a |
awk '/^[^ ]/ { printf ("%s\"%s\"", s, $1); s="," }'
```

If there's a trailing colon on the interface name field, you can fix that by using `awk -F:`.

Answer (score 1):

**One way using `GNU find` and `/sys/class/net/`:**

```
find /sys/class/net/ ! -type d -printf "\"%f\"," | sed 's/,$/\n/'
```

**One way parsing `ifconfig -a`:**

```
ifconfig -a | sed -ne '/^[^ ]/ { s/^\([^ ]\+\).*/"\1"/; H }' -e '$ { g; s/\n//; s/\n/,/g; p }'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a list of interfaces, this should work:

```
echo $(ifconfig | sed -n '/^[[:alnum:]]*:/s/:.*//p')
```

If you really need the commas between the items, then you could add the following pipe:

```
| sed 's/ /,/g'
```

and if you really want double quotes and commas, then you could add the following pipe:

```
| sed -e 's/ /","/g' -e 's/.*/"&"/'
```